# How can I fix this weird third person camera behavior?

Tags: unity-game-engine, cinemachine

Ok, so I've been playing a lot of Devil May Cry 1 recently and I found out that I really like third person Hack and Slash games. So I wanted to make something similar using Unity. The character controller I've set up works pretty well for my needs. There is just one problem. The third person camera (Free Look Camera) has like this weird FieldOfView-Change whenever the character is moving.

[Click here to see what it looks like right now!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbaca.gif)

I tried fixing that by changing its properties on the side but it didn't help at all, heck, it even got worse.
Maybe there is a really simple solution for it but I didn't get there.

All I want the camera to do is follow the player smoothly (which it does) but without doing that weird Snap-Back-In-Place-After-Player-Has-Stopped-Thingy (which it does not).

Have you guys got any ideas?
Thx, Anton

Comment: Can you post your Camera script ?

Comment: Doesn't look like field of view but simply distance to the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with Cinemachine. From the camera, I can tell this is what you're using. Cinemachine has a lot of options, but you need to locate damping and turn that off if you don't want that delay.
Hopefully this resolves your issue!